# Xcode 4 and GData compile problem

Tags: iphone, gdata, xcode4

After upgrading to the GM version of Xcode 4 I can't compile my projects that make use of GData (e.g., YouTube API provided by Google).  In particular, it complains about GDataFeedYouTubeVideo because it does not recognize it. This is the exact same project that compiled just fine in Xcode 3.x.

In Xcode 3.x, you use to be able to drag a folder from one project to another project.  Looks like this feature is removed from Xcode 4.  Does anybody know how to do this in Xcode 4?

Comment: I think Xcode 4 is still under NDA and as such we cannot answer your questions about it here.

Comment: If he is willing to wait a few months for an answer we could probably come back to it on release.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I figured the answer to the first question and will post the second question on the developer.apple.com forum (forgot about the NDA on xcode4).

Answer (score 0):

If GDataFeedYouTubeVideo is a file that should not be compiled then you can manually remove it from the 'Compile Sources' list in your Target settings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with my gdata api.  follow link for what I did
[linking gdata to an xcode 4 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379644/linking-gdata-to-an-xcode-4-project)