# linking gdata to an xcode 4 project

Tags: iphone, xcode, reference, xcode4, gdata

I'm having major issues linking gdata to a project after upgrading from xcode 3.2.5 to xcode 4.  I would like to know if anyone is having similar issues, and what did they do to resolve them.  i am using gdata version 1.11 which is the latest on their site.  The project works flawlessly on 3.2.5, thanks.

I have created a workspace for my project, and then added the gdata.proj to it.  So I do have all the files linked by reference.  But project files which include #import "GDataYouTube.h" do not see the file.  I get "No Such File or Directory"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good News...  resolved and tested, all working follow these steps...

Open your project in xcode 4 from 3.2

click File -> Save As Workspace

in project navigator on the left, collapse your Project if you see all the files

below your collapsed project, in the empty space right click or control click -> Add Files to...

select the project file you wish to link to, leave Copy items unchecked, click Add

Now you will see 2 collapsed projects in your Project navigator, expand both

Now what I didn't know I had to still do

Drag the files or folders you want from the second project to your main, make sure your Main project target is selected in the options, and I also have group selected then click Finish

You are good to go, you might have some warnings about your second project and its targeted SDK.  Fix those by clicking the project name in the Project Navigator -> Build Settings -> Base SDK to 10.6, Deployment Target to 10.5

Comment: Great news! Please mark your question as answered so people don't waste time seeing if you still need help...

Comment: Ah. I barely remember the early member restrictions. :-)

Comment: My experience…I had to restart Xcode before this worked, selecting the Workspace file from the Welcome screen…otherwise, it would just add the flat project file without an expand option.